# Vertex buffer not clearing properly

Tags: c++, 3d, 2d, vulkan

### **Context**

I'm a beginner in 3D graphics and I'm starting out with Vulkan, which I already know it's not recommended save it please, currently working on a university project to develop the base of a 3D computer graphics engine based on the Vulkan API.

### **The problem**

[Example of running the app to render the classic 2D triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TsnE.png)

[Drawing a 3D mesh after having drawn the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Faapi.png)

So as you can see in the images above I want to be able to:

1. Run the engine.
2. Choose an object to be drawn.
3. Close the window.
4. Choose another object to be drawn.
5. Open the same window back up with only the last object chosen visible.

And the way I have been doing this is by essentially cleaning up the whole swap chain and recreating it from scratch once the window is closed and a new object has been chosen. Now I'm aware this probably sounds like terrorism for any computer graphics engineer but the reason I'm doing this is because I don't know a better way, I have just finished the vulkan tutorial.

### **Solutions tried**

1. I have checked that I do a vkDestroyBuffer and vkFreeMemory on the current vertex buffer before recreating it again once I choose a different object.
2. I have disabled depth testing entirely in case it had something to do with it, it doesn't.

**Note:** The code is extensive and I really don't have a clue of which part of it could be relevant to the problem, so I opted for not cluttering the question, if there is an specific part you think it might help you find the solution please request it.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What's the loadOp on your renderpass? Possibly you're just ending up rendering on top of old frame data.

Comment: @solidpixel I have `colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;` `colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;` `colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;`
`colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;`

Comment: How do you even choose the object to draw? Why not just pick which to draw with arguments in your draw function? Also, try using renderdoc for debugging.

Comment: @user369070 Hey thanks a lot, based on your comment I managed to find the problem. Basically my readOBJ function just took whatever vertices were in the OBJ file and just added them to the data structure I use to store them before passing them to the vertex buffer without cleaning it first. Hence why it only happened when I chose to draw a 3D object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment by user369070 ended up drawing my attention to the function I use to read OBJ files which made me realize that this function wasn't cleaning a data structure I use to store the vertices of the object chosen to be drawn before passing them to the vertex buffer.

I just had to add `vertices = {};` at the top of the function to solve it.